# How to determine which covariates to use

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, model-selection, predictor

This may seem like a basic question but here goes...  I am looking at the effect of brain stimulation on skill acquisition across several timepoints.  I have several measures that may be useful as covariates to control for individual differences on task learning such as baseline performance, age, gender etc.  How do I determine which, if any, of these to use as a covariate in my repeated measures ANOVA (or ANCOVA)?  None of these individual measures are significantly different across groups.  I generally use SPSS- but CAN use R if needed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This can be a nontrivial topic and whole field of study is devoted to it called model selection. You can look into model selection criteria such as AIC, BIC, etc.

Comment: Frank Harrell's book "Regression modeling strategies" has a nice section on this issue.